# Basic Python code works differently on new machine (Mac)

Tags: python, macos

I just started my new M1 MacBook and since Python2.7 is preinstalled, I wanted to run a little harmonic series program in the terminal to compare to my old Mac (old Intel). A silly test, I know.

```
import time

t_1=time.time()
x=1
i=1
while x<20:
        i+=1
        x+=1/i
        if i % 1e6 == 0: print(i,x);

print(i)
t_2=time.time()
print(str(t_2-t_1)+' s')
```

It turned out that only on the M1 Mac the program was not running as expected, since x did not increase. I had to change `x+=1/i` to `x+=1/float(i)` so `x` was understood as a float and not 'rounded' to 1 (staying an int). I thought that, while the latter is actual the more correct way to program, python is flexible with variables, and my most important question is of course: Why does this work differently on different machines?

Comment: Handling numbers on a division is one of the differences beetween Python 2 and Python 3. You probably used Python 3 before

Comment: it has nothing to do with the computers, you just happened to have different python versions

Comment: I am sorry for the stupid question. I was actually not aware I was using Python 3 on the old machine.

Answer (score 0):

In python2.7 the `/` is integer division. If you import

```py
from __future__ import division
```

at the top of your file, then you can use `/` for float division.

If you still want to be able to use integer division, you can always use `//`.